# How can I add a simple png picture to my bokeh website?

Tags: python, bokeh, python-3.7

I alread tried to add a picture by using a div container, but I always got a 404 error: "404 GET img/image.png (my-ip) 1.27ms".

What i'm doing wrong. Due to a similar issue on stackoverflow that method should work - I guess.

```py
image_div = Div(text="<img src='img/image.png'>")

curdoc().add_root(image_div)


>> bokeh serve /dir/image.py --allow-websocket-origin=my-website:5006
```

Comment: Did you specify your image location as static in server code? So that it serves those files as well, either make it static or serve it using some hosting servers or AWS S3 or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser 100% cannot load *local filesytem paths* from a remote server. The images must be hosted and served by a real web server, ie. they must have actual `http` (or `https`) URLs in the `img` tag. You have three basic options:

- Serve the images from some other remote web server
- Run separate web server on this machine to serve the image files
- Make the Bokeh app be a [directory style Bokeh app](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format) which can serve files in a `static` subdirectory.

Which one is best for you depends heavily on the particulars of your situation.